# Is it possible to reuse shingles/replace only part of the shingles?

Tags: roof, shingles

My back porch roof is collapsing. You can see in this photo how the left side is bowed down tremendously:

[image: Porch roof is collapsing]

Obviously, I want to fix the roof and make it actually sturdy. I lifted the shingles there in the corner and discovered that much of the wood in that corner has rotted away. I don't know if it was like that before they put the siding on, but it's really bad, and I worry about it collapsing, especially when my children are playing out there.

Is it possible to save the shingles that are currently on the porch roof there and reuse them? If that's not possible/recommended, is it at least possible to only have to replace the shingles on part of the roof, as opposed to the whole thing?

Answer (score 1):

I would say yes for sure on this.  You are going to have to pry them off more carefully.  Note that the nails/staples should only be under the other shingles.  If put on wrong it could make it difficult to reuse.

The only reason I am suggesting reusing is that you met two criteria:
1. You have a small area and you don't want a color mismatch.
2. That area is outside of a living space.

I would personally reuse them.  I would try to keep the row(s) between the house and porch attached if you can.  This will be your we spot and you will need to retrofit that first row under.  You would want this on the porch in case of future potential leaks.